# List operator on multiple character classes without using matching group

Tags: regex

I want to extend the regular expression `[a-z0-9]` to become Unicode-inclusive. `[a-z]` becomes `\p{Ll}` or `[:lower:]` and `[0-9]` becomes `\d` or `[:digit:]`. But what does `[a-z0-9]` become? I know that you can express it as `(\p{Ll}|\d)`. But I don't want to introduce another matching group into my expression. So can I express `[a-z0-9]` in a Unicode-inclusive manner without using a matching group?

Comment: There is no specific construct/shorthand for lowercase letters and digits. Use `[\p{Ll}\d]`

Comment: That works. Answer with that and I'll accept it.

Comment: Since you try to be more inclusive of all characters, maybe you could apply `\p{N}` which would mean any kind of numeric character in any script (instead of `\d`)

Comment: @JvdV Right, probably it will be a better bet with Unicode property classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific construct/shorthand for lowercase letters and digits.

You need to create your own character class for that:

```
[\p{Ll}\p{N}]
[[:lower:][:digit:]]
```